# Can I move someone else's dolphin?

Tags: escape-from-atlantis

We recently purchased a copy of the original [Escape From Atlantis](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/24037/escape-atlantis) as it was a game I used to love as a child. Playing it last night, however, we came across a couple of situations that the rules didn't seem to clarify.

If a player has an Atlantian on the same tile as a dolphin, and is using that dolphin for travel, can I 1) move a swimmer on to that tile and "steal" the dolphin away from them on a later turn, or 2) when rolling a dolphin move, cause their dolphin to "abandon" them and swim away?

We're unsure as to whether that dolphin effectively becomes "theirs" or not, where only a shark or a sea monster can get that person, or if stealing a dolphin is fair game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dolphins don't belong to anyone. In my version of the rules (UK), the only thing a Dolphin does is let you pay 3 movement points (I.E your entire turn) to move a swimmer and dolphin to the safety of a coral island, and leave the dolphin in front of the island.

You can move the dolphin with the swirler without having any effect on the swimmer(s) present.

I think different editions have different rules though.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. This clarifies things greatly, and we'll give it a go next time we play (later, probably).